# Incompatible type error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

[image: error]

An error shows when I build the gradle second time after opening the project. At the first time, the gradle build does not show any errors.

Can someone help?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code and error messages as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `import` statement. Be sure that you imported `java.util.List`, not some kind of `java.awt.List` or something else.

Also, check your `ListView` import.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your own `ArrayList` class and it does not implement the `List` interface. Hence you cannot assign its objects to a `List` variable.